# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
namespace ttt
{
    public partial class student : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-R0N4ID3;Initial Catalog=testOnedb;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand com;
        SqlDataReader read;

        public student()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            com = new SqlCommand("select * from testOnetable",conn);
            conn.Open();
            com.ExecuteReader();

            SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("the username : " + read["username"].ToString() + "\n the passward : " + read["passward"].ToString() + "\n the email : " + read["email"].ToString());
            }

            read.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the initialization of your database interaction elements (e.g. the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader`) in `using` blocks so the `Dispose` methods are invoked when you're done with them (or manually do it):

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from testOnetable", conn))
using (SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader()) {
    ....
}
```

Closing the `SqlDataReader` doesn't dispose of its hold on things (I'm not sure on the technical details in particular for it).

Also, opening a new connection every time you build a new `student` instance is not nice to the database. You should use a singleton pattern and have a dedicated data access object class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the

```
com.ExecuteReader();
```

from your code, that line is useless as you are not assigning the reference to the reader (in the next line you get the reference and assign that correctly in your variable "reader")

Answer (score 0):

Your first call of `ExecuteReader()` is probably not wanted.

Change

```
...
conn.Open();
com.ExecuteReader();

SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();
...
```

to:

```
...
conn.Open();
```

If you intentionally want two readers open simultaneously, set `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string, as explained here: [C# Using 2 sqldatareader at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803039/c-sharp-using-2-sqldatareader-at-same-time)

Some other things: You're dealing with disposables here, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`. You should call `Dispose()` on them when they are no longer needed of even better wrap a `using` around them, so that they get disposed automatically.

It's also often a good idea to keep variables as local as possible. It doesn't seem like the connection the command or the reader really need to be members of the class as you only use them in the constructor. Consider pushing them in the constructor all together. Like that you can also use `using` for disposal of them. Otherwise you had to add and destructor and dispose them there.

```
public partial class student : Form
{
    public student()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-R0N4ID3;Initial Catalog=testOnedb;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from testOnetable", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (read.Read())
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("the username : " + read["username"].ToString() + "\n the passward : " + read["passward"].ToString() + "\n the email : " + read["email"].ToString());
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void student_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: SqlConnection can be initiated in the class, and then you can call `conn.ConnectionString` in the SqlConnection constructor within the method instead of rewriting it. Also, `conn.Close();` is unneeded, since the using(SqlConnection ...) will dispose the connection automatically.